# How to sum every 2 consecutive vectors using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How to sum every 2 consecutive vectors using numpy. Or the mean of every 2 consecutive vectors.
The list of lists (that can have even or uneven number of vectors.)
example:

```
[[2,2], [1,2], [1,1], [2,2]] --> [[3,4], [3,3]]
```

Maybe something like this but using numpy and something that actually works on array of vectors and not an array of integers. Or maybe some sort of array comprehension if the that exists.

```
def pairwiseSum(lst, n): 
    sum = 0; 
    for i in range(len(lst)-1):           
        # adding the alternate numbers 
        sum = lst[i] + lst[i + 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 def mean_consecutive_vectors(lst, step):
    idx_list = list(range(step, len(lst), step))
    new_lst = np.split(lst, idx_list)
    return np.mean(new_lst, axis=1)
```

Same could be done with `np.sum()` instead of `np.mean()`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the idx_list part? That's a single element list.... How does the np.split use it? Why did you create it with range?

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape your array into pairs, which will allow you to use `np.sum()` or `np.mean()` directly by providing the correct axis:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,2], [1,2], [1,1], [2,2]]) 

np.sum(a.reshape(-1, 2, 2), axis=1)

# array([[3, 4],
#        [3, 3]])
```

Edit to address comment:

To get a the means of each adjacent pair, you can add slices of the original array and broadcast division by 2:

```
> a = np.array([[2,2], [1,2], [1,1], [2,2], [11, 10], [20, 30]]) 

> (a[:-1] + a[1:])/2

array([[ 1.5,  2. ],
       [ 1. ,  1.5],
       [ 1.5,  1.5],
       [ 6.5,  6. ],
       [15.5, 20. ]])
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted to get the mean of every vector and the one after it and not just "every twos"?

Comment: @tibetish you can just add slices and divide by 2: `(a[:-1] + a[1:]) / 2` See edit above.

Comment: Great! That looks a lot easier and straight forward. I tried using np.mean() and then figured I'm sure how to refer to the array's elements.